# can we set the data labels out of the slice if it is not fit in +highchart?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am using a highchart library and my issue is, if the value of slice is less than 5% it will not fit in the slice area, What I need is if the value is smaller like 1%,2% etc it will go out side of slice as in below URL:
[sample image](https://spiritualplaydate.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/SP_Pie-Chart-Rev-4_3_16.jpg)

```
$('#chart01').highcharts({
    chart: {
      height: 290,
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false,
        style: {
            fontFamily: 'OpenSansRegular'
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: '70',
        align: 'center',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        y: -25,
        style: {
            fontSize: "40"
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                distance: -15,
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.point.y + "%";
                },
                style: {
                    //fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: 'white',
                    textOutline: false
                }
            },
            showInLegend: true
        }
    },
    legend: {
        width: 345,
        height: 150,
        itemWidth: 172,
        itemMarginBottom: 5,
        labelFormatter: function () {
            var words = this.name.split(/[\s]+/);
            var numWordsPerLine = 3;
            var str = [];
            for (var word in words) {
                if (word > 0 && word % numWordsPerLine == 0) str.push('<br>');
                str.push(words[word]);
            }
            return str.join(' ');
        }
    },
    series: [{
        colors: ['#04a15c', '#c038f3', '#5e9bfc', '#f39938', '#7c4ce9', '#e94c6b'],
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Vendor invoices',
        innerSize: '65%',
        data: [
            ['19 Draft', 20]
            , ['10 Paid', 35]
            , ['11 Submitted', 4]
            , ['25 In review', 15]
            , ['40 Approved', 10]
            , ['15 Rejected', 1]
        ]
    }],
    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 300
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    width: 255,
                    itemWidth: 125,
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                    layout: 'horizontal'
                }
            }
        }]
    }
});
```

a pen is created so you can check the issue,
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/hami/pen/ypKOvg)

In this Image I want 1% should be out of the slice.

[image: sample image]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uz7x17xs/) demo

Add events load and redraw function in chart parameter

```
  chart: {
    height: 290,
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: 0,
    plotShadow: false,
    style: {
      fontFamily: 'OpenSansRegular'
    },
    events: {
      load: function() {  //when chart is loaded action
        this.series[0].data.map((el) => {
          if (el.y < 2) { //if value is less than 2
            el.dataLabel.attr({
              y: el.dataLabel.y - 25
            });
            el.dataLabel.text.attr({
              style: "color:black"
            });
          }
        })
      },
      redraw: function() { //when chart is redraw or resized action
        this.series[0].data.map((el) => {
          if (el.y < 2) { //if value is less than 2
            el.dataLabel.attr({
              y: el.dataLabel.y - 25
            });
            el.dataLabel.text.attr({
              style: "color:black"
            });
          }
        })
      }
    }
  },
```

Update:

only load event is required and it updates with datalabels where value is less and as result datalabels comes out of chart.

```
  load: function() {
    this.series[0].data.map((el) => {
      if (el.y < 2) {
        el.update({
          dataLabels: {
            distance: 5 //updates with datalabels distance
          }
        })
        el.dataLabel.text.attr({
          style: "color:black"
        });
      }
    })
  },
```

[Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/0j4zknfe/) fiddle

Comment: thanks for your effort, but this solution will only work for this place of pie slice.. can we set the value of distance in attribute??

Comment: problem here is x and y value for datalabel which differ for circular chart. finding way to solve this.

Comment: Added distance in attribute dynamically. check updates